# C# Refresh Explorer

Tags: c#, winapi, refresh, explorer

In my program I toggle the registry value of hidden files to tell explorer whether to hide or show them.  However, since explorer doesn't refresh on it's own, I send the event

```
 SHChangeNotify(0x8000000, 0x1000, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
```

to refresh everything.  However, it doesn't seem to be refreshing anything unfortunately.  I see the screen on the desktop flicker a bit, but in order to see the changes, I have to manually refresh the folder.  SHChangeNotify doesn't seem to be working for me.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to update the registry settings and then send an F5 key to the current window. It takes very little code, but it's never ideal to use SendKeys and it only updates the view for the current window.

```
static void ShowHide()
{
    string AdvKey = @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced";
    bool Hidden = (int)Registry.GetValue(AdvKey, "Hidden", 0) == 1;
    int h1 = 1; int h2 = 1;
    if (Hidden) { h1 = 2; h2 = 0; }
    Registry.SetValue(AdvKey, "Hidden", h1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    Registry.SetValue(AdvKey, "ShowSuperHidden", h2, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    Thread.Sleep(100); //A small wait is needed here to ensure the registry is updated
    SendKeys.SendWait("{F5}"); //This updates the current window
    SHChangeNotify(0x08000000, 0x1000, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero); //This may update the other windows
}

[DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern void SHChangeNotify(uint wEventId, uint uFlags, IntPtr dwItem1, IntPtr dwItem2);
```

A better method is to use the SHGetSetSettings API. This will reliably update the view in all Explorer Windows and updates the settings in the registry as well. The code below is based on an answer posted [here](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1010138).

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
    public extern static void SHGetSetSettings(ref Structures.SHELLSTATE lpss, Structures.SSF dwMask, bool bSet);

    internal static class Structures
    {
        [Flags]
        public enum SSF : int
        {
            SSF_SHOWALLOBJECTS = 0x00000001,
            SSF_SHOWSUPERHIDDEN = 0x00040000,
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct SHELLSTATE
        {
            public uint bitvector;

            public uint FShowAllObjects
            {
                get => this.bitvector & 1;
                set => this.bitvector = value | this.bitvector;
            }

            public uint FShowSuperHidden
            {
                get => (this.bitvector & 0x8000) / 0x8000;
                set => this.bitvector = (value * 0x8000) | this.bitvector;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void ToggleHiddenFiles(bool bShow)
    {
        Structures.SHELLSTATE state = new Structures.SHELLSTATE();

        state.FShowAllObjects = (uint)(bShow ? 1 : 2);
        state.FShowSuperHidden = (uint)(bShow ? 1 : 0);

        SHGetSetSettings(ref state, Structures.SSF.SSF_SHOWALLOBJECTS | Structures.SSF.SSF_SHOWSUPERHIDDEN, true);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        string AdvKey = @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced";
        bool Hidden = (int)Registry.GetValue(AdvKey, "Hidden", 0) == 1;
        ToggleHiddenFiles(!Hidden);
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by not writing to random values in the registry. The registry is not a programming interface. If you need to refresh a shell view call [`IShellView::Refresh()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellview-refresh).

Comment: @IInspectable Answer revised.

Answer (score -1):

Try SHGetSetSettings with your change to fShowAllObjects

A simple Get and Set with SHGetSetSettings won't work though.

It's smart enough to compare it's current settings to what your sending it and will only notify other windows of the change if the two are different.

To refresh the desktop use IShellWindows to enumerate shell windows, check the IWebBrowser2.FullName property to skip IE windows and then call IWebBrowser2::Refresh.

Comment: Could I have a code snippet?  I tried to use SHGetSetSettings and it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: http://www.google.com/codesearch?as_q=SHGetSetSettings&btnG=Search+Code&hl=en&as_lang=c%23&as_license_restrict=i&as_license=&as_package=&as_filename=&as_case=

Comment: var shellState = new SHELLSTATE();
            shellState.fShowExtensions = 1;
            SHGetSetSettings(ref shellState, SSF.SSF_SHOWEXTENSIONS, true);
^^^ That's what I'm doing in my code.  Still doesn't help. :\

Comment: mmm, try change HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced first, then broadcastWM_SETTINGCHANGE with "ShellState" and SMTO_ABORTIFHUNGm. If that does not work try SHChangeNotify with SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED and SHCNF_IDLIST